# Why "HOST" field is required in HTTP request?

Tags: http

I have known one ip address can map to multiple hosts, but http server can resolve the domain from request line(Request-Line = Method SP **Request-URI** SP HTTP-Version CRLF) of request header, so why the "HOST" field is necessary?

Comment: There is no host name in the `Request-URI`.

Comment: In case we don’t use host field, is it mandatory to type the host+path as Request-URI? So the server could know the host name in request line?

Comment: The host field is mandatory. If you omit it, you get error 400.